# Delay click event on <a> element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there a way to hold the execution of the default action of a click even trigger on an `<a>` element and resume it later?

I specifically do not mean cancelling the event and rewriting it later, as in:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event){
  var url = this.getAttribute("href");
  var target = this.getAttribute("target");
  event.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("TODO: open " + url + " in " + target);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">Click me!</a>
```

… neither triggering a brand new click:

```js
var delayed = false;
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event){
  var link = this;
  if (!delayed) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function(){
      link.click();
    }, 1000);
    delayed = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">Click me!</a>
```

```js
function cloneEvent(event) {
    return Object.setPrototypeOf(new Event(event.type), event);
}

var delayed = false;
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event){
  var newEvent = cloneEvent(event);
  if (!delayed) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function(){
      event.target.dispatchEvent(newEvent);
    }, 1000);
    delayed = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">Click me!</a>
```

Why not?

1. Rewriting means you need to reinvent everything the browser would you (error prone and time consuming).
2. Triggering means it's no longer a user-initiated event (e.g. popup blocker) and the event cloning version doesn't even work.
3. I'm curious (main reason).

I get the impression that [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) puts the event in a final state. Am I correct? Is it just not possible?

Comment: You can call the url directly, but pop up blockers will block actions like these. There is no way to delay it without manually triggering it.

Answer (score 0):

On the link set `href='about:blank'` which qualifies as a genuine user click and then add `data-href=`*url*. The **eventListener** passes the `data-href` value through to a function wrapped in an anonymous function which is **set Timed out**. The function `activateLink()` uses `location.href` to open the link.

### Demo

```js
var lnx = document.links;

lnx[0].addEventListener('click', delayClick, false);
lnx.jsi.addEventListener('click', delayClick, false);
lnx.so.addEventListener('click', delayClick, false);

function delayClick(e) {
  let destination = this.dataset.href;
  setTimeout(function(e) {
    activateLink(destination)
  }, 1000);
}

function activateLink(destination) {
  location.href = destination;
}
```

```css
a {
  display:block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<a href='about:blank' data-href='https://example.com' target='_blank'>EXAMPLE</a>

<a id='jsi' href='about:blank' data-href='https://javascript.info' target='_blank'>JAVASCRIPT.INFO</a>

<a name='so' href='about:blank' data-href='https://stackoverflow.com' target='_blank'>STACKOVERFLOW</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but, unless I'm missing something, it's just an elaborate implementation of approach #1 (though without the event cancellation part). My question is more a curiosity about the possibilities of the `Event` web API than an actual problem solving.

Comment: Basically if you are using a tag that has an event tied into it by default such as a link, you'll need to use `e.preventDefault()` or you get that undesirable behavior (i.e. instant jump). I have provided a way to jump with the delay, inhibit the default behavior without `e.preventDefault();` and technically fired the click event. Does Approach #1 work? If approach #1 works, does it jump after a second delay? The reason why it's elaborate is because when you click a link w/o `e.prevDef` you can't get that delay under normal context. If this or e.target is readily available, you can't be delayd